# How does stale object life-cycle works for Nginx?

Tags: nginx, proxy, cache

I'm using nginx (1.8.0) to serve content. I setup it up to respond stale (`proxy_cache_use_stale`)  while `updating` and others. I noticed that it was responding with **404 responses** while it was `updating` its cache, I thought only `2xx` responses were served as stale.

How does an object (an HTTP response) enters, leave and gets updated as stale?

How can one mitigate this effect? (I mean to update the stale version from 404 to the latest valid 200)

Sample conf: `nginx.conf`

```
http {
    proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout updating invalid_header;
    proxy_cache_valid 404 10s;

    server {
      location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_cache_key $http_x_scheme$http_x_fe_host$uri;
        proxy_cache_lock on;
        proxy_cache_lock_timeout 5s;
      }
    }

    server {
      listen 8080;
    }

}
```

Comment: I read through their caching guide https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-caching-guide/ and saw this:

`Expired (stale) content is deleted only when it has not been accessed for the time specified by inactive. When expired content is accessed, NGINX refreshes it from the origin server and resets the inactive timer.`

For me, the **404** stale response should be updated to the fresh **2xx** but this is not happening.

Comment: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#proxy-everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was because I was sometimes generating a floating point for `max-age` HTTP header and then Nginx did these strange behaviors, like no updating a stale object.